# Strange issue with NavigationView on iPad (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, ipados

I have used NavigationView like this for iPhone and iPad, and in iPhone works fine. But for iPad, sometimes when enter a NavigationLink - it will go to the new view, then enter the same view again... and again for a few times!

```
NavigationView {
  WidgetEditor(widgetSize: $widgetSize)
    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        NavigationLink(destination: AppsView()) {
                        ...
        }
      }
                
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        NavigationLink(destination: HelpView()) {
          Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
        }
      }
   }
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

I suspect it is the last line that cause the issue, but I need the NavigationView to looks like iPhone not dual panes.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to put it into a ToolbarItemGroup like this example
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbar(content:)-5w0tj

Comment: Can you attach a gif or video?

Comment: Quang Hà, if put both into group, that means both buttons will be on one side (either leading or trailing).

Comment: Hi aheze, it is just entering the same view again and again for a few times.